# Unexpected EOF?

Tags: bash, loops, gnuplot, eof

I have been trying to create a graph in GNUPLOT using Bash. As I understand it, my following code should input the following lines into the gnuplot command until it reaches an EOF. I then send the "set" lines and "plot" line to gnuplot and follow it up with an EOF, which should end the input into the gnuplot command.

```
for FILE in ./tempFolder*.done; do
    gnuplot <<EOF
    set datafile separator ","
    set xlabel "Hour"
    set ylabel "Temperature"
    set term png
    set output "${FILE}.png"
    plot "${FILE}" using 1:3 with errorbars title "Temperature/Time"
    EOF
done
```

However, I get the following error message: "Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")"

When I type try this in Bash outside of the script, it seems to work properly. Anyone have any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot indent the closing `EOF`; it has to be at the beginning of the line.

If you use `<<-EOF` instead of `<<EOF`, the shell will strip any leading *tabs* from each line of the here document, including the closing `EOF`.

Comment: @CarriePiazza Please accept the answer if the solution worked for you. Thanks.